# Bash script file reading

Tags: bash, file, for-loop

I'm trying to select certain text from an output file.

I'm reading my file as follows:

```
while read line 
do
    if [ "$line" == "SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION" ]; then
        break
    fi
done < tutorial1/Tutorial1_1.out
```

When the loop reaches that "Summary" line, i need to read only the next 9 lines. I'm trying to use a for loop but i'm not sure how to use it:

```
for i in {1..9}
do
    read line < tutorial1/Tutorial1_1.out
    echo $line >> Summary.out
done
```

My output is as follows:

```
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
next is setrmt
```

But i need it to be the next 9 lines after the "SUMMARY" statement. Please help.

Comment: Where's the file you're reading really?  Is it in `tutorial1/Tutorial1_1.out` or in `../Tutorial1_1.out`?  These are different files unless `tutorial1` is a symlink to the parent directory.

Comment: Sorry about that, the file is in /tutorial1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect again. That reopens the file at the beginning. Do the second block inside the first and use the same file descriptor:

```
while read line 
do
    if [ "$line" == "SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION" ]; then
        for i in {1..9}
        do
            read line
            echo $line >> Summary.out
        done
        break
    fi
done < tutorial1/Tutorial1_1.out
```

Comment: You can also replace the entire `for` loop with `head` when sharing the file descriptor. `{ while read line; do if [ ... ]; then break; fi; done; head -9 > Summary.out; } < tutorial1/Tutorial1_1.out`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-A` parameter for the `grep` command like:

```
grep -A9 "SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION"
```

from the man:

> **-A NUM, --after-context=NUM**
>
> ```
>           Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.
> ```

demo:

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < <(grep -A9 "SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION" filename | tail -9)
```

for the next input file

```
before1
before2
before3
before4
before5
before6
SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
line10
line11
line12
```

prints:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
line7
line8
line9
```

or simply:

```
 grep -A9 "SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION" ../Tutorial1_1.out | tail -9 >> Summary.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a clean solution:

1) find the line number of the line that contains the string you want. You could do this by implementing a counter, but this is better:

`linenr=$(grep -n -m 1 "SUMMARY OF POLARIZATION CALCULATION" <your file name here> | cut -d':' -f1)`

2) calculate the number of the last line you want:

`let "lastlinenr = $linenr + 9"`

3) fetch the lines and write them to a file:

`cat <your file name here> | sed -n "$linenr","$lastlinenr"p > <your destination file here>`

Comment: I tried this method, but it returns an empty string.